# The name 'Dispatcher' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, dispatcher

I have a problem with dispatcher. My program is used for watching a particular folder.

My code is here:

```
if (watcherChangeTypes == System.IO.WatcherChangeTypes.Renamed)
   Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { AddlistLine(string.Format("{0}->{1} to -> {2} at {3} ", watcherChangeTypes.ToString(), oldName, name, DateTime.Now)); }));
```

But I have mistake the name dispatcher does not exist in current context.
I have declared using `system.threading;` 
but it did not work.

Comment: Do you declare your `Dispatcher`? Please show more complete code.

Answer (score 5):

You must import WindowsBase
and then add

using System.Windows.Threading;

Here is the microsoft reference

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you are referencing WindowsBase.dll as well. It needs this. Add reference > Assemblies > Framework.